# Classification with Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify samples into two classes, positive and negative.
I have 500 positive samples and 100 negative. examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ZvD.jpg
(I dont have enough reputation to post images or multiple links)

I am using a convolutional neural network to do the classification. For negative samples which have an obvious distortion, the network works fine. The problem is with negative samples that have a small distortion, they are classified as positive.

Does anyone have any suggestions ? Maybe pre-processing steps or completely another methode rather than CNN ?
Thank you

Comment: What framework are you using for the CNN? On of your problems may be, that you 4x more positive than negative samples. There are techniques to work around that, some frameworks bring this with them.

Comment: I am using AlexNet (Alex Krizhevsky) framework

Comment: i use about 600 positives and 500 negative face images for training my face detection module using CNN and it gives me an accuracy of about 95% over 800 test images. probably increasing the number of negative image set can help you improve the accuracy.

Comment: Can you get more negative examples? Else you could use data augmentation to increase the number of negative images, but making 500 out of 100 examples may be a bit too much.